# Why does my program not work (reverse function in python help)?

Tags: python, function

I've made a program what had been set for homework in computer science. I've found a new, very unfamiliar function which won't seem to work as expected.

I'm new to this forum.
P.S. I also do it as a hobby, I'm not just here for anwsers

```
def reverse():
    s3 = ''
    for char in reversed(s3):
        s3 = s3 + char

def match_char():
    global s1
    global s2
    global s3
    s1 = input('What is your first string? ')
    s2 = input('What is your next string?  ')

    reverse(s2)

    num_matches = 0
    for i in range(len(s1)):
       if s1[i] == s2[i]:              
            num_matches = num_matches + 1

    return num_matches
```

Comment: Do you have a question?  Perhaps something more specific than "why doesn't it work?"  Or details on how you expect it to work and the behavior you have observed...

Comment: @JoranBeasley he/she defines `reverse`

Comment: _As written_ your reverse function won't do anything, the indentation is not right and you've passed it a variable without defining any arguments in the declaration. These might just be transcription errors though, can you provide example input and output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In python, strings are immutable.  So when you do:

```
reverse(s2)
```

Some things happen inside of `reverse`, but your string that you passed in is unchanged.

To fix, you first want to `return` from your function:

```
def reverse(my_str):
    s3 = ''
    for char in reversed(my_str):
        s3 = s3 + char
    return s3
```

And then assign over `s2` when you call `reverse`:

```
s2 = reverse(s2)
```

There are lots of other ways to improve your code, but that's the explanation of your "unexpected" results.

Comment: He would want to pass an argument to `reverse`, we presume (all those globals are burning my eyes)

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
reversed_s3 = s3[::-1]
>>> s = 'abc'
>>> s[::-1]
'cba'
```

As a function:

```
def reverse(s):
    return s[::-1]
```

More thoughts about the following bit of code:

```
> def reverse():
>     s3 = ''
>     for char in reversed(s3):
>         s3 = s3 + char
```

It calls `reversed()`, which is a generator. So simply try this:

```
>>> s = 'abc'
>>> s = list(reversed(s))
>>> s
['c', 'b', 'a']
>>> s = ''.join(s)
>>> s
'cba'
```

Comment: So if `s = 'abc'` then what happens with `s.reverse()`? str objects don't have a `.reverse()` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

As well as the other two very valid answers I would add that you're not actually taking any arguments in your reverse function so even though you are correctly passing a string in no processing is being done to it (and nothing is returned as roippi pointed out).

```
def reverse():
```

needs to be

```
def reverse(string):
```